I want to json compare in the postman
I want to compare 2 different responses in postman. But while doing this, I want it to ignore the fact that the order is different. I just want to see whether the values ​​in one are also in the other and whether the results are the same. How can I do that
I tried this script but even though the 2 responses were different "
Response is identical to other response | I got the response "AssertionError: expected false to be true".


pm.test('Response is identical to other response', function() {
    const yeniResponse = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('yeniResponse'));
    const eskiResponse = pm.response.json();

    const isEqual = _.isEqual(yeniResponse, eskiResponse);
    pm.expect(isEqual).to.be.true;
});



